# Embedding Kibana (Elastic Search) into WordPress?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I'm really after some advice here please.

I have a membership website, and I am using WordPress to manage access to my paid subscriptions.

I'm interested in Kibana in terms of its' data visualization but my question is really one of whether I'm using it for the wrong purposes?

My point is: can Kibana be embedded and made to look white-labelled?

I'm pretty sure Kibana is really meant for internal use hence my question.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes that is possible. You can create various [visualizations](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/visualize.html) and have them integrated into one [dashboard](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/dashboard.html) in Kibana.

This dashboard feature has capability to *share* these visualizations as discussed in this [LINK](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/sharing-dashboards.html). As an example, the share URL comes in the below format:

```
<iframe src="http://abc.myserver.com:5601/app/kibana#/dashboard/a6c99100-b2b2-11e7-8aa0-9fc1ad35f7e7?embed=true&_g=()" height="600" width="800"></iframe>
```

You can either share the current state of the dashboard with your users, *or* share them the most recent view of the dashboard whenever they reload their page.

Let me know if it helps.